# VB.net .exe cannot be run from another computer. Missing assemblies for ClosedXML

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, closedxml

I must put this program into production today, and I can't get it to run independently.

In the program, I have included NuGet package "Imports ClosedXML.Excel" and use it to create spreadsheets.  When I build my executable, and try to run it from another computer, it cannot find the ClosedXML and Documentformat.OpenXml assemblies.

I checked in References that "Copy Local" was = True for ClosedXML and Documentformat.OpenXml, but it's not working.  I found another website that mentioned Global Assembly Cache, and that if the dependency is in there, it will not be included in the Build .exe.

I am running Visual Studio Professional 2017.  I am in over my head on this one, so if you have answer (and I hope you do), please try to provide it in elementary terms I can understand.

Comment: Did you copy (or otherwise install) all the .dll files from the "Release" folder along with your program's .exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes issue is solved by individually adding application files inside the following menu

Go to `Publish-->Application Files`

Select `Show all files`

Under `Publish Status`
Set the files you need to `Include`  [not include(auto)]

[image]

Comment: That did the trick.  Now I am able to run the .exe independently.  I do wonder what the difference is between Include(Auto) and Include.

Comment: Correction:  It in fact didn't work.  I did not see at first that I already has the needed .dll files in the test folder.  Once I removed them and clicked the .exe, I received the same error message.

Comment: when you recompile (rebuild), does it add those dll files to the folder?